# how to select one value if true or false in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. Is there any function to do these? (can anyone tell me how to call this? )

For example:

```
 string str = boolVar: "trueA" || "falseA";// if boolVar = true => return string trueA
```

or

```
 var abb = booVar: "stringIfTrue" || 3.14; //if boolVar == false => return double 3.14
```

Comment: `string str = boolVar ? "trueA" : "falseA";`  The second example won't work at all because the possible results are of different types, and C# is statically typed.

Comment: Note that your types must be compatible with the ternary operator.  `double` and `string` are not.

Comment: @Glorin `[dynamic,Object]  abb = booVar ? "stringIfTrue" : 3.14;` will work

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot how about int and double?

Comment: @Seb o! really?  but why?

Comment: @kingyau Both items must be castable in 'abb' type, not necessarily the same type

Comment: @Seb dynamic/object will not work with incompatible types either. The ternary operator looks at the types *supplied to the operator*, not the return type you expect. Try it and you'll see this compiler error: `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'double'`

Comment: @Seb so why i cannot use Var? It should be work as you said.

Comment: And dynamic type will be resolved at runtime.

Comment: @kingyau int and double would work as there is an implicit conversion. The ternary would return the broader type (a double, in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Tim has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39295264/1025555) the first case can easily be done with the *conditional operator* (sometimes also called *ternary operator*).

If you really, really, *really* want to make the second line work as well you can use .NET's [`dynamic` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx):

```
dynamic abb = booVar? "stringIfTrue" : (dynamic)3.14;
```

You have to cast at least one of the last two operands to `(dynamic)` though.

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [conditional operator ?:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
string result = boolVar ? "stringIfTrue" : "stringIfFalse";
```